# error: The named parameter 'child' isn't defined

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

i try to change it in children but it doesn't change anything
i've tried

> 1. flutter clean
> 2. pub get

but it show the same error

```dart
void main() {
 runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ScreenUtilInit(
     designSize: Size(375,812),
     allowFontScaling: false,
     child: MaterialApp(
       debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
       title: "Presence",
       theme: ThemeData(
         scaffoldBackgroundColor: Constants.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
         visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
         textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(),
       ),
       initialRoute: "/",
       onGenerateRoute: _onGenerateRoute,
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: Show ScreenUtilInit class and the where did you called ScreenUtilInit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a builder instead.

From the `flutter_screenutil` readme:

```
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: const Size(360, 690),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      splitScreenMode: true,
      builder: (context , child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'First Method',
          // You can use the library anywhere in the app even in theme
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            textTheme: Typography.englishLike2018.apply(fontSizeFactor: 1.sp),
          ),
          home: child,
        );
      },
      child: const HomePage(title: 'First Method'),
    );
```

Comment: i've used builder and it worked thanks like that   builder: () => MaterialApp()

Answer (score 0):

In which widget are you trying to call child?

Comment: This is more of asking about clarification and not an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must need to declare home inside `MaterialApp` and give your initial page to that.